# Redefining previously defined class in CSS with tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can anyone explain the following CSS code?

```
.main aside {
             background: linear-gradient(white,  pink); 
                }
```

where main is a CSS class.

Comment: What is there to explain? You should really read a basic tutorial on CSS...

Answer (score 1):

That rule applies to each `aside` tag (not *class*) which is inside an element that has class `main`

example:

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div>
      <aside>
       ... (rule applies here)
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure we should be encouraging people to ask super basic tutorial questions.

Comment: @AndrewLi It's supposed to be downvoted as showing no research and definitely not given an answer.